# UIbutton frame and addtarget is different

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

I make custom view and there create button add on view.
In View Controller

```
MyCustomView *customView = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
[customView.button addTarget:self action:@selector(goodTry) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But if I touch my button in frame only down mean line is touchable, upper of mean line addTarget does not working.

```
 ----
|\   |      
|*\  |
|**\ |
|***\| 
 ----
```

-- It is my button frame. Where `***` - it is working. Where empty place doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The drawing is the customView or the button? Is it the same size?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 it is a `UIControlEvent` that he has to add here not a `UIControlState` that will just throw an error or at the very least a warning. `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` should work if everything else is done correctly. How do you create the buttons on the customView?

Comment: Avi, drawing is for button. Size of CustomView  and my button is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your button frame lies inside the parent's frame. Area of button outside Parent's frame freezes and doesn't respond to touch events. Set `clipToBounds = YES;` on button to test it.

Answer (score 3):

Add background color for button and check how and where the button positioned.If it positioned outside of your custom view you can't perform action with that outside portion.